# How to show entity detail in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i try to make when i click button ,pop-up will open and show more datail in it but i have a error. I did not access to server side i mean when i put the breakpoint in c# code (public JsonResult PersonalDetail(int personalId)) ,program do not go there and it show noting
 please help me :)

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="personalDetailModel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    @if(Model != null) { 
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Personal Name :</b>@Model.PName
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Personal Lastname :</b>@Model.PLastname
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Personal Email :</b> @Model.Email
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Personal Phone :</b>@Model.Phone
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  }
</div>
</div>
```

this is my model and i want to show personal detail in this pop-up

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info"  onclick="ShowDetail(@item.PersonalID)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#personalDetailModel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" ></i></a>
```

And i use this button for access the pop-up and enter to script

```
var ShowDetail = function (PersoID) {
        var prsnID = $("#personalDetailModel").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Personal/PersonalDetail",
            data: { PersoID: prsnID },
            success: function () {

            }
        })
    }
```

And this is script. So i want to take more detail from PersonalID and i will show it in pop-up

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult PersonalDetail(int personalId)
        {

            StorageSystemEntities2 db = new StorageSystemEntities2();


            Personal personal = db.Personal.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PersonalID == personalId);
            PersonalViewModel personalVM = new PersonalViewModel();

            personalVM.PName = personal.PName;
            personalVM.PLastname = personal.PLastname;
            personalVM.PAuthorisation = personal.PAuthorisation;
            personalVM.JobStartDate = personal.JobStartDate;
            personalVM.DOB = personal.DOB;
            personalVM.Email = personal.Email;
            personalVM.Phone = personal.Phone;
            personalVM.ShopName = personal.Shop.SName;
            personalVM.GenderType = personal.Gender.GenderN;
            personalVM.PStatus = personal.PStatus;

            return Json(personalVM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: so with your code don't go call on api side right??

Comment: Is ajax error in browser console?

Comment: can you please show your error?

Comment: you can here change your code data: { PersoID: PersoID}, and please this PersoID pass on your server side.

Comment: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"     i take this error

Comment: i am saying in comment try this wave and let me know it's working or not?

Comment: and make sure you have to ajax call time PersoID not a null value pass.

Comment: i did what you sad . it goes call on api side but it is not show data in pop-up @coderwill

Answer (score 0):

Its is because the method on front-end doesn't match the method at the backend. What you need to do is to match the parameters name as well. like

```
data: { personalId: prsnID },
```

and

```
public JsonResult PersonalDetail(string personalId)
```

Also you need to set parameter type to string, because it doesn't by default cast your type into int so change that into string in parameter on server side and cast it in method.